# Alterações remotas no branch não vem para o local

Tags: git, bitbucket

Tenho uma estrutura simples de branchs no repositório (bitbucket), o master, onde fica o código de produção e uma outra branch releases, este para testes.

Foram feitas alterações no branch releases e feito o push.
Quando eu faço o pull, vejo as alterações, classes criadas, etc. Mas elas não "aparecem" no código.

Tentando resolver, fiz o merge remotamente, para a branch master, e fiz o pull, também não desceu as alterações feitas.

Espero ter sido claro, muito obrigado!

O que posso fazer neste caso? Somente clonando o projeto novamente?

Answer (score 1):

Confere se você está utilizando o branch correto.
Você pode baixar todos os branches de um repositório, mas é necessário selecionar qual vai utilizar. No caso, se as alterações estiverem no master, vai utiliza-las por padrão, se não troca pro releases.

Comment: O branch está correto. As alterações vieram, mas o código em si nao  alterou, se faço a pesquisa por uma classe criada, eu consigo achá-la. Já fiz tb o git add . mas não houve alterações. E, se for feito novamente o pull, diz que já está atualizado.